# How can I show a date in Urdu?

Tags: 8, theming, i18n-l10n, datetime

I am working on printing dates in more than a language. With Drupal 7, I used the following code.

```html
<span class="arabic-date">
 <?php
   $arrayurdudays = array('', '', '', '', '', '', '', '');
   print format_date(time(), 'custom', ' l , d F , Y', null, 'ur');
 ?>
</span>
```

With Drupal 8 and Twig, I tried more than one way and it didn't work for me.

I downloaded the *Configuration Translation* module, but it didn't work in my case; I read there is a way to print it inside a file (.theme), but I didn't understand the method well. I need it inside the header file.

> [image: Figure previously in Drupal 7]

> [image: In Drupal 8]

Comment: Does this help? [Twig date() documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/date.html)

Comment: This works in the names of days and months in English, but I need to display them in the names of days and months in Urdu

Answer (score 1):

In a Twig template, you can use the `format_date()` filter. For example, in the node template, the following code could be used to show (using a custom format) when a node has been created. (The following code is a simplified version of the code used from the Unami theme used with the *Unami Demo* installation profile, in [node.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21profiles%21demo_umami%21themes%21umami%21templates%21content%21node.html.twig/9.0.x).)

```twig
{% set created_date = node.getCreatedTime|format_date('custom', 'l, d F, Y', null, 'ur') %}

{% if display_submitted %}
  <footer class="node__meta">
    <div{{ author_attributes.addClass('node__submitted') }}>
      {% trans %}<span class="by-author">by {{ author_name }}</span> {{ created_date }}{% endtrans %}
    </div>
  </footer>
{% endif %}
```

I would rather avoid passing a language code to `format_date()` to let the filter use the language set for the page. Setting the language code would make the template file always use that, even if the page is using a different language code.

```twig
{% set created_date = node.getCreatedTime|format_date('custom', 'l, d F, Y') %}

{% if display_submitted %}
  <footer class="node__meta">
    <div{{ author_attributes.addClass('node__submitted') }}>
      {% trans %}<span class="by-author">by {{ author_name }}</span> {{ created_date }}{% endtrans %}
    </div>
  </footer>
{% endif %}
```

Note that when the custom format is using *M* for the month, the month name could be not correctly translated. See [Date formats with abbreviated month name (M) are not translated using context](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3004425) for more details.